# md-material not allowing child divs to fill 100% height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Im having an issue where the md-content wont let my map object fill the md-content div. It ends up allways being 300px tall. The width is correctly 100% tho. The md-content div is filling the whole row div. How do I get the md-content to alloow he map to be 100%

```
 <div flex layout="row">
   <md-content flex>
     <map zoom="8" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></map>
   </md-content>
 </div>
```

Comment: Provide more context.

Comment: A plunkr would be appreciated.